# WHERE CURRENT OF in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor

1. Why we need `WHERE CURRENT OF` clause in `Oracle PL/SQL`? We all know that `FETCH` retrieves only one row at a time and hence `FETCH` is used in `LOOP` to process all the rows of a cursor. Then why do we exclusively need a `WHERE CURRENT OF` clause? We can anyhow lock the cursor rows using `FOR UPDATE` or `FOR UPDATE OF`.
2. Can rows be unlocked (which are locked by `FOR UPDATE` or `FOR UPDATE OF`) once we close the cursor? Or do we need to `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK` the transaction to unlock the rows?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at this block:

```
DECLARE

    CURSOR c1 IS
    SELECT course_number, ROWID AS RID
    FROM courses_tbl
    FOR UPDATE;

begin

    FOR aCourse IN c1 LOOP

        UPDATE courses_tbl SET course_number = aCourse.course_number + 1 
        WHERE CURRENT OF c1;
        UPDATE courses_tbl SET course_number = aCourse.course_number + 1 
        WHERE ROWID = aCourse.RID

    end loop;

end;
```

The two UPDATE statements are equivalent, `WHERE CURRENT OF ...` is just a shortcut for `WHERE ROWID = ...`, you can use either of them.

Actually your question should be "Why we need `FOR UPDATE ...`?"  The reason is, the ROWID may change by other operations, e.g. `ALTER TABLE ... SHRINK SPACE`, moving tablespace or big DML's. `FOR UPDATE` locks the row, i.e. ensures that ROWID does not change until you finished your transaction.

No, you can release the lock only by finishing the transaction, i.e. `ROLLBACK` or `COMMIT`

Answer (score 0):

1. May be this will convince you ...

> When we want to update or delete the cursor fetched row(s) from the
>   database, we don’t have to form a UPDATE or a DELETE statement with a
>   primary key mapping in its WHERE clause, instead, the WHERE CURRENT OF
>   clause comes in handy.

**Source**: 
http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_adv_plsql_for_update_where_current.htm

2. You must commit or rollback your transaction to release locks.