# Oracle procedure to increment dates

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to increment a date based upon a condition (while a date is bigger than the other):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE schema.procedura
 AS

dt_lst DATE;
dt_md  DATE;
eu_val INT;

BEGIN

  for i in (select rowid, TABLELORIK.* from TABLELORIK)

LOOP

   dt_md  := to_date('20290401','YYYYMMDD');
   dt_lst := to_date('20190802','YYYYMMDD');
   eu_val := 180

 while  dt_md > dt_lst 
  LOOP
   dt_lst := dt_lst + eu_val;
  END LOOP;

  UPDATE TABLELORIK set DATE_COL = to_char(dt_lst,'YYYYMMDD') where rowid=i.rowid;
  COMMIT;

END LOOP;
END procedura;
/
```

My desired output in this case is DATE_COL = 20281212 (Which in fact is smaller that dt_md and the loop should stop there!)

What my loop output is in this case: 20290610 (an extra +180 days (one more loop step and now the condition dt_md > dt_lst is broken))

Can someone help me with this last step to stop the loop and not pass dt_md.

Comment: Why do you want to do this in a loop? Or with PL/SQL at all? (And why are you storing dates as strings!?)

Comment: The quick fix would be `... WHILE dt_md > dt_lst + eu_val LOOP ...`. But I think this doesn't need any slow, procedural part.

Comment: No need for a loop or a procedure, it's a simple calculation: `dt_lst + trunc((dt_md-dt_lst) / 180) * 180`

Comment: Why on earth do you store `DATE` values as s strings (or number)? Don't do that, convert column `DATE_COL` to proper `DATE` data type.

Comment: As already stated by others there is no need for a loop. Apart from that, when you use `WHERE ROWID = ...` then you should lock the records with `FOR UPDATE`, otherwise the `ROWID` may change. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49110728/where-current-of-in-pl-sql/49111174#49111174

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your `while` loop to quit *before* dt_lst is greater than dt_md, you have to say so. Try this:

```
while dt_md > dt_lst + eu_val
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need either loop in your code, and don't need to use PL/SQL.

You can calculate the target date directly:

```
select to_date('20190802','YYYYMMDD')
  + 180 * trunc((to_date('20290401','YYYYMMDD') - to_date('20190802','YYYYMMDD'))/180)
from dual;

TO_DATE('2
----------
2028-12-12
```

or with date literals:

```
select date '2019-08-02' + 180 * trunc((date '2029-04-01' - date '2019-08-02')/180)
from dual;
```

The difference between two dates is a number or days. `date '2029-04-01' - date '2019-08-02'` gives you 3530. You want to know how many complete multiples of 180 fit into that, so divide by 180, which gives 19.6111...; truncate that to 19; multiple that by 180 again to get the actual number of days you want, 3420; and finally add that back to your starting date.

And then to update all rows in your table at once:

```
update TABLELORIK
set date_col = date '2019-08-02' + 180 * trunc((date '2029-04-01' - date '2019-08-02')/180);
```

If your column is really a string then wrap that in a `to_char()`, but you shouldn't be storing dates as string.

You could make that into a procedure, but there doesn't seem to be much point.

Even if this is a assignment to increment in a loop, you don't need to update each row in the table one by one; and you don't need to recalculate `dt_lst` every time (unless the assignment is actually to adjust the original column value, rather than all to the same fixed date):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE procedura
AS

  dt_lst DATE;
  dt_md  DATE;
  eu_val INTEGER;

BEGIN

  dt_md  := date '2029-04-01';
  dt_lst := date '2019-08-02';
  eu_val := 180;

  while dt_lst + eu_val <= dt_md
  LOOP
    dt_lst := dt_lst + eu_val;
  END LOOP;

  UPDATE TABLELORIK set DATE_COL = dt_lst;

END procedura;
/

insert into TABLELORIK (id, date_col) values (1, sysdate);
insert into TABLELORIK (id, date_col) values (2, null);

exec procedura;

select * from TABLELORIK;

        ID DATE_COL  
---------- ----------
         1 2028-12-12
         2 2028-12-12
```