# CURRENT in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I've noticed that `CURRENT` is a reserved keyword for BigQuery at: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/lexical.

What exactly does `CURRENT` do? I've only seen it as a prefix for things such as `CURRENT_TIME()`, `CURRENT_DATE()`, and other such stuff but have never seen it by itself. Is this just reserved for future usage or do any SQL statements contain that as a keyword?

Comment: **CURRENT** keyword seems to be reserved as a part of SQL 2016 spec.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_reserved_words
And you can check it's usage in another DBMS implementations like Oracle, SQL Server.
hope this is helpful.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49110728/where-current-of-in-pl-sql

Comment: SQL Server>> delete from MyTable where CURRENT OF cursorName

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to add on the comment of @Jaytiger:

> **CURRENT** keyword seems to be reserved as a part of SQL 2016 spec. en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_reserved_words And you can check it's usage
> in another DBMS implementations like Oracle, SQL Server. hope this is
> helpful.
> stackoverflow.com/questions/49110728/where-current-of-in-pl-sql

In BigQuery **CURRENT** clause is used on defining [frame_start and frame_end](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/window-function-calls#def_window_frame) in [window functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/window-function-calls).

> A window function, also known as an analytic function, computes values
> over a group of rows and returns a single result for each row.

A common usage for this is calculating a [cumulative sum](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/window-function-calls#compute_a_cumulative_sum) for each category in the table. See [BigQuery window function examples](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/window-function-calls#window_function_examples) for reference.

Comment: thanks. Is there a way to search the Google BigQuery documentation for a particular word across all pages? For example, something like "BigQuery CURRENT" (case-sensitive) ? Or rather, how do you find where the reserved keywords are used in BigQuery in a more general case?

Comment: @carl.hiass Most of the reserved keywords and how to use them are found [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax). But surprisingly CURRENT is not included in this page. I will submit a documentation feedback about this.